# Set constant variables in Ruby (that would not be modified)

Tags: ruby

I have an issue with my code where

```
def foo 
   var_original = var
   while something
     answer = modify! var #here we modify var in while loop
   end
   print var_original
   answer
end
```

//var_original is a matrix object in my code

**var_original** somehow returns value of **var** even though it was never invoked in my function after it was assigned.

My goal is to get `var` to be equal to what it was started with before returning `answer`.
I wanted to do `var = var_original` but only to realize that `var_original` was somehow also changed for absolutely no reason.

With this issue, I came up with a question if I could set up `var_original` to lock for being modified. I found answer on the forum with $global_variables, but they didn't solve my issue after I turned `var_original` into `$var_original`.

Is there any other possible solution where I can lock `var_original` from getting modified?
Here is my code (pretty sure the whole part is not really needed, just to show that I do not invoke `original_map` anywhere else).

```
def solve(minemap, miner, exit)
    original_map = minemap
    origins = miner
    list = []
    while true
        break if miner == exit
        if minemap[miner["x"]][miner["y"]].class == TrueClass
            possibles = find_possibles(minemap, miner)
            minemap[miner["x"]][miner["y"]] = [true, nil, possibles]
        elsif minemap[miner["x"]][miner["y"]].class == Array
            if minemap[miner["x"]][miner["y"]][1] == nil
                miner = charge!(minemap, miner, list)
            else
                temp_miner = miner
                teleport?(minemap, miner, list)
                if temp_miner == miner && minemap[miner["x"]][miner["y"]][2] == 0
                    minemap[miner["x"]][miner["y"]] = false
                end
            end
        else
            miner = origins
        end
    end
    print original_map #Prints minemap, but it should be original_map (crying)
    puts
    list
end

def find_possibles(minemap, miner)
    possibles = []
    if !minemap[miner["x"]][miner["y"] + 1].nil?
        possibles << "down"  if minemap[miner["x"]][miner["y"] + 1] == true && miner["y"] + 1 < minemap.size
    end
    if !minemap[miner["x"]][miner["y"] - 1].nil?
        possibles << "up" if minemap[miner["x"]][miner["y"] - 1] == true && miner["y"] - 1 >= 0
    end
    if !minemap[miner["x"] - 1].nil?
        possibles << "left" if minemap[miner["x"] - 1][miner["y"]] == true && miner["x"] - 1 >= 0
    end
    if !minemap[miner["x"] + 1].nil?
        possibles << "right" if minemap[miner["x"] + 1][miner["y"]] == true && miner["x"] + 1 < minemap.size
    end
    possibles
end

def charge!(minemap, miner, list)
    temp = minemap[miner["x"]][miner["y"]][2].shift
    list << temp
    minemap[miner["x"]][miner["y"]][1] = temp
    case temp
        when "down"
            miner["y"] += 1
        when "up"
            miner["y"] -= 1
        when "right"
            miner["x"] += 1
        when "left"
            miner["x"] -= 1
    end
    miner
end

def teleport?(minemap, miner, list)
    temp = minemap[miner["x"]][miner["y"]][1]
    list << temp
    case temp
        when "right"
            return miner if minemap[miner["x"]][miner["y"] + 1] == false
            miner["x"] += 1 if minemap[miner["x"]][miner["y"] + 1][2].size > 0
        when "left"
            return miner if minemap[miner["x"]][miner["y"] - 1] == false
            miner["x"] -= 1 if minemap[miner["x"]][miner["y"] - 1][2].size > 0
        when "up"
            return miner if minemap[miner["x"] - 1][miner["y"]] == false
            miner["y"] -= 1 if minemap[miner["x"] - 1][miner["y"]][2].size > 0
        when "down"
            return miner if minemap[miner["x"] + 1][miner["y"]] == false
            miner["y"] += 1 if minemap[miner["x"] + 1][miner["y"]][2].size > 0
    end
    miner
end

minemap = [[true, false],
    [true, true]]
puts solve(minemap, {'x'=>0,'y'=>0}, {'x'=>1,'y'=>0}) #== ['right']
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. In the first line of your `foo` method you assign `var_original = var`. Why are you surprised that `var_original` returns the value of `var` after that?

Comment: var gets modified like it is written in pseudocode to get answer that is going to get returned at the last moment. Right before it I wan to assign var to var original that should be different since i only modified var, not var_original.

Comment: So, let me get this straight. You are trying to make `var_original` a deep copy of `var`? The reason you are having issues with `var_original` changing is due to the fact that you are changing both `var_original` and `var` due to your assignment.

Comment: Lets say I have idx0 = 0;  idx1 = idx0; idx1 += 1; print idx0 should be still be 0, and it does so. I only want to receive value, not its pointer. With this example, I recieve vlaue. I dont understand why matrix doesn't work that way, it is still only an object.

Comment: "here we modify var in while loop" – No, you don't modify `var`. You modify the *object referenced by `var`* (and `var_original`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comment, you'll be wanting `var_original` to be a deep copy of `var`. For instance, you would do the following:

```
var_original = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(var))
```

This way, whenever you change `var`, `var_original` is not changed.

Comment: Still makes no sense why one object gets a pointer and other a value from "var1 = var2". I guess I have to accept it and move on. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There's one thing missing from your mental model. `var` is not the object. It's a **reference** to the object.

```
 var_original = var
```

That makes `var_original` point to the same object in memory that `var` points to. Since that object is now accessible through either reference, if you change it via `var`, you'll see the changes via `var_original`. What you want is called "deep copying/cloning". Look it up.

Comment: Why then "idx0 = 0; idx1 = idx0; idx1 += 1; print idx0" prints 0? Shouldn't it work the same way for all objects, simply because they are objects?
If I would make a refence (pointer) then I should get 1, not 0.

Comment: @Mikhail: nope, because you are __reassigning__ `idx1` to point to __another__ object, `1`. And `idx0` keeps pointing to the original object, `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply, doing

```
var_original = var.dup
```

Will most probably work.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ohh..it has solved a similar issue for me. Will `.clone` help? And if not both, would be glad to learn the reason.

Comment: Because it's a complex structure. And `.dup` only does shallow copying (and we need deep copying here)